# How to remove elements inside specified index of array using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I need to remove some elements inside an array with specified index. I am trying to use slice function for it but it is giving me undefined error.

This is my controller code:

```
if($scope.startColm<$scope.endColm){
//Suppose here startColm value is 1 and endColm value is 4

  for(var j=0;j<rowCellData.length;j++){
  //rowCellData is an array. Attaching its image for reference

    for(var k=$scope.startColm;k<($scope.endColm-$scope.startColm);k++){

      var cellData=rowCellData[j].slice($scope.startColm,$scope.endColm)
      //Here i want to remove data inside rowCellData from specified index.
    }
  }
}
```

rowCellData consists data like this:
[image]

Inside each index there is some data which I need to fetch based on the specified startColm and endColm value. Like here i want the data from 1st to 4th position for all the index of rowCellData.

[image]

Please suggest how to remove data inside array elements.

Comment: In think you are trying to make a slice method over an Object instead of an Array.

Comment: you want to remove property from a object , not an object from an array i think.

Comment: so how can i remove property from object based on the start and end position value

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Answer (score 0):

You want the 'splice' method, not the 'slice' method. However, since you have objects inside the main array and not other arrays, you could use delete to remove the items:

```
for (var i = $scope.startColm; i <= $scope.endColm; i++) { 
  delete rowCellData[j][i] 
}
```

Comment: getting the same undefined error. "rowCellData[j].splice is not a function"

Comment: oh, i just realized you have objects, not arrays inside. You could simply for over the range then and remove things with something like `for (var i = $scope.startColm; i < $scope.endColm; i++) { delete rowCellData[j][i] }`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, but i want to retain the value from startColm index to endColm index and want to delete all other values. Please suggest how can i achieve this

Comment: can a rowCellData object contain any number of cells (i.e I see from 0 to 10) or is it max 10 or a known number?

Comment: it can contain any number of data

Comment: then it's not so easy especially because you have an object with some numbers AND other keys in it and you want to remove all numbers except a range - this can be done using Object.keys(rowCellData[j]) to iterate all keys (0, 1, ... ,'Attained Age', ..) of the object and then selectively remove it (using delete as shown) if the key is a number AND is not within range.